# measuring time to receive POST data in a PHP/Apache script

Tags: php, apache2

I'd like to know how much time it takes for each of my clients to POST data back to the server. Other than measuring this on the client and posting it back to the server, is there a server side only way to measure this?

There appears to be a server variable REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT, but that seems to contain the microsecond timestamp since the script was started (which, ostensibly, is after the POST data was received).

So doing something like this:

```
$posttime = (microtime(true) - floatval($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT']));
```

doesn't actually include the download time for the POST request. Any ideas anyone on how the complete POST transfer time could be measured server side only?

Comment: you can't know, the server has no idea when the post was initiated.

Comment: sure it does. That's the time apache writes into the log as when the request was received. Not when it finished. But the precision of this timestamp isn't good enough (plus it's a pain to try and extract it from the log). So would be better if that was somewhere in the server environment. Seems to me that's a metric that should attract considerable interest.

Comment: yes received, not sent

Comment: the server knows when the connection was opened, it also knows when the transfer has finished and the connection closed. That metric would be very useful to have. Perhaps there's an apache option I can't find that exposes this to the PHP (or any other scripting) environment?